# Project my screen-broken Lumia 930 on any device

Tags: lock-screen, nokia-lumia-930, password, display

The screen of my Lumia 930 is broken and the touch-screen capability is dead. I can not access my files using USB because my screen is locked with a passcode. This also prevents me from using Microsoft's Project my Screen App.

Is there a way to project the screen of my screen-broken Lumia 930 on any device (PC , Smart TV, Ipad) to unlock my screen and access my files (photos, videos)?

Comment: Sounds more like you should get the screen repaired. If you set the device up to upload to OneDrive, then just leaving it in WiFi range should suffice to get the content backed up (which could even be restored to a new device, if it proves uneconomic to repair)